# How to start two algorithms using different threads and only take the output from the first algorithm to finish?

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have two algorithms that are capable of solving Sudoku puzzles. The first uses a dancing links algorithm (a form of recursive backtracking) the other uses constraint propagation followed by recursive backtracking.

I would like to start both algorithms with their own thread and I only want the output from the first to finish. Because both will have the same output (or at least both will have an acceptable output), I want to take the answer from the first to finish and kill the other thread.

Sometimes of the algorithms can take 100+ seconds to finish on puzzles perfectly made to trip up that algorithm, but they I haven't found a puzzle that trips up both algorithms.

Do I need to mark the threads as Daemon? I'm getting answers with the following code, I'm just worried it's not doing what I hope it's doing.

Edit: after further reading its looking like maybe i actually want to use multiprocessing instead of threading. I'm going to test both and see how they compare.

```
import threading
import time
import queue

from dlx import dlx_solve
from norvig import norvig_solve

# Test grids:
grid1 = '003020600900305001001806400008102900700000008006708200002609500800203009005010300'
grid2 = '4.....8.5.3..........7......2.....6.....8.4......1.......6.3.7.5..2.....1.4......'
hard1 = '.....6....59.....82....8....45........3........6..3.54...325..6..................'

def solve(algo, grid, worker_queue, id, stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():

        ans = algo(grid)

        if not stop_event.is_set():
            worker_queue.put((ans, id))

        break


# queue for workers
worker_queue = queue.Queue()

# indicator for other threads to stop
stop_event = threading.Event()

# run workers
threads = []
threads.append(threading.Thread(target=solve, args=(dlx_solve, grid1, worker_queue, 'dlx', stop_event)))
threads.append(threading.Thread(target=solve, args=(norvig_solve, grid1, worker_queue, 'norvig', stop_event)))


for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

# this will block until the first element is in the queue
first_finished = worker_queue.get()

print(first_finished)
```

Comment: You aren't setting the stop_event, but other than that you seem to have already sorted it out. Marking the threads as daemons would kill them when all non-daemon threads have exited and that could be bad if they hold any of resources that need to be released and means that you have to kill the whole program to stop those threads. Oh, and your algorithms have to check the stop_event every so often, right now you seem to only check it after having already finished, and you've got a loop with an unconditional break in it (not a loop at all, just redundant)

Comment: If your algorithm is in pure python (as opposed to doing the heavy lifting in numpy or something) then yes, you may want to use multiple processes instead of threads.

Comment: How do i go about setting the stop event? And since im using pure python multithreading wont actually work in parallel right? wont the interpreter lock stop it?

Comment: Pure python and the need to terminate (as opposed to voluntarily exiting on a signal) speaks for multiprocessing, yes. You'd supply each job with a queue to deposit the result in, and terminate both processes when something shows up in the queue. (Use multiprocessing.Queue, not queue.Queue) -- threading would only help you if the work was done in a C module or other program (each thread would be waiting on a blocking call)